# Subtitles/Translations On or Off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

- [Spanish subtitles for Tron: The next day](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2987/51)
- [Are there any better English translations of Solaris available, beyond the original translation from French?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1387/51)

Particularly on the first link, there seems to be some question if translation/subtitle locations are on topic. Disregarding legal implications, that is to say assuming we only are going to allow linking to sources of official or otherwise legal translations/subtitles, should these kinds of questions be on topic?

Examples of legal sources would be versions of shows/movies that have the desired subtitles but that were removed from or added to different physical mediums; or out-of-print copies of alternate language versions of books or author-sanctioned translations or possibly even academic translations.

Answer (score 1):

The first seems like a shopping question, which IIRC are considered off-topic SE-wide.  If the question is "is there a version that has Spanish subtitles", rather than "where do I find ...", then it seems on-topic to me.

I think the second one is definitely on-topic (asking for "better" translations invites bad answers that have no reasoning, but there could also be good subjective answers).

It seems like a perfectly reasonable topic for our site, roughly coming under the "Behind-the-scenes and fandom information" on-topic list.  (Assuming, as you have, that questions/answers about illegal material are unacceptable).

IMO they are similar to questions about different editions of books (e.g. [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2058/are-there-differences-in-the-authors-note-in-different-bio-of-a-space-tyrant)), which do not seem to be controversial. In addition, questions like this may be particularly useful to those whose first language is not English, which would be a great addition to the site.

Comment: I tend to agree. :) However, to be clear, it is not a shopping question. Tron: The Next Day, is a short film that was released online as a teaser for the 3rd movie.

Comment: @DampeS8N your edit makes the question much clearer and more clearly not a shopping question.

Comment: Cool. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a category that can be decided on- or off-topic as a whole.

Questions about the existence of published translations of written SF into English are often answered by a single link to [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.com/) (so we *might* end up closing them as general reference). Other media or languages [don't seem to have such a resource](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54/is-there-a-reasonably-complete-online-database-of-sf-works). For example, information about what DVD editions have subtitles in what languages is hard to find — but then we get into the different issue of [shopping questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/499/are-shopping-questions-on-topic). I can't see a reason to reject questions about planned translations (as long as there's some substance, e.g. rumors to substantiate or disprove).

Fansubbing and fan translations are a difficult issue: these are generally unauthorized and therefore a breach of copyright. While I sympathize with the desire of people to have translations in their language, explicit references to illegal material (or to very-probably-illegal material) can't be left on the site. But this is something that needs to be decided on a case-by-case basis (there are authorized fansubs, there are works that are out of copyright in some locales…).