# Are questions on finding material on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are shopping questions on topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/499/are-shopping-questions-on-topic)

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10605/where-can-i-find-spring-1153#comment19165_10605

There seem to be similar questions on the site still open as per the comments, so I'm assuming it's OK. Right?

Comment: See: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/814/is-asking-where-to-purchase-something-on-topic