# Is this request for a translation on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There's about 15 seconds of speech in Russian in the film *2001: A Space Odyssey*. The subtitles on the DVD don't show what they're saying. I didn't see any other requests for translation with the [translation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) tag. Would it be on-topic to ask what they said?

I realize that this site is for science fiction experts, not experts in Russian, but at least one person on the site knows Russian. [This meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/497/subtitles-translations-on-or-off-topic) is related, but it doesn't make it clear whether my question would be on topic.

**Update:** I posted my question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125321/what-do-the-russian-scientists-say-in-this-scene-of-2001-a-space-odyssey).

Comment: [This site](http://www.underview.com/asofaqs.html#faqj) addresses my question, but the way it reads, it sounds like the person who wrote that doesn't know whether it's true.

Comment: I was about to say "no, take it to Russian Language SE", when I found precedents: [one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109372/what-do-the-arabic-dialogues-in-the-league-of-extraordinary-gentlemen-say), [two](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112330/what-does-oliver-queen-say-in-russian). So **yes**.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Guess I should have kept looking. I expected translation requests to have the [tag:translation] tag.

Comment: @amarillo maybe they'd be better tagged with the language in need of translation?

Comment: I didn't know we had a translation tag! Editing now!

Comment: My question hit Hot Network Questions, so I suppose one way to try to get a question answered is to put it on any site, and then hope a Russian expert sees it in the HNQ list.

Comment: ....and it worked. Someone with a Russian-looking name just popped in and made their first post on the site as an answer to my question.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Interestingly, simple requests for translation are *off-topic* on most of the language sites, including Russian:SE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Requesting a translation to English of a *specific short* passage or clip in a foreign language, in a work of SF/F written mainly in English, is on-topic.**

None of the following questions have ever been VTCed, giving us a clear precedent:

- [What does Oliver Queen say in Russian?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112330/what-does-oliver-queen-say-in-russian)
- [What is this Norwegian shouting?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105419/what-is-this-norwegian-shouting)
- [What do the Arabic dialogues in the League of Extraordinary Gentlemen say?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109372/what-do-the-arabic-dialogues-in-the-league-of-extraordinary-gentlemen-say)

A good rationale for this policy would be that understanding what's being said in such passages/clips may be important for complete understanding of what's going on in the book/film. Often they're just for flavour, giving the reader/watcher the atmosphere of being in a foreign country or around foreign speakers, but there will always be perfectionists who want to understand every last thing being said, especially on a site like this.

<sub>Usual disclaimers apply: please don't start flooding the site with questions asking for translations of every foreign-language clip in every SFF film ever.</sub>

Comment: Let me know if I missed any loopholes that would allow for silly questions to be posted while sticking to the letter of what I just said is on-topic ...

Comment: Thanks. If only I could ask for the entirety of *Solaris* (1972) to be translated, just in case the subtitles missed something...

Comment: I was going to point out my question, but you already had. Whoo, free publicity!