# Jacksonverse tag for Peter Jackson "Tolkien"- based movies?

Tags: feature-request

We use the term "Jacksonverse" to describe the liberties Peter Jackson took with the *Hobbit* . Since so many Tolkien questions on this site turn on the differences between the books and the movies, I think having a "[jacksonverse](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jacksonverse)" or "[peter-jackson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peter-jackson)" tag would help organize them better.

*(.....aaaaand IMO should be used instead of [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium) for such questions, because they're about material Tolkien never wrote or saw. But that's just a matter of preference; simply having the tag is more important.)*

Comment: I like this idea, but actually implementing it would require another big tag editing event. Also, note that we do already have a [tag:movie] tag, which is often used on film-specific [tag:tolkiens-legendarium] questions.

Comment: I agree with @Rand. Just use the 'movie' tag to differentiate. The 'Jacksonverse' is not its own universe, rather it's a subset of the 'Tolkienverse'.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, then someone can become an expert in [tag:movie]s and I thought that you thought that was wrong?

Comment: @Edlothiad Nothing wrong with someone being an expert in the LotR movies (well, except that they're dreadful betrayals of a great work of literature, but they're still a thing that people can be experts in, just like any other book or film).

Comment: Yes but then you'd be an expert in movies in general, unless we had a lotr specific movie tag.

Comment: There's been a lot of effort put into stopping me having a gold tag in 'movies' :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tolkien tags - the way forward](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10655/tolkien-tags-the-way-forward)

Answer (score 6):

In theory, distinguishing the Jackson Hobbit and LOTR movies from other parts of the "legendarium" is a fine and noble ambition.

In practice, however I see a number of key difficulties.

1) **The sheer scale of what you're proposing**. With hundreds of questions about the films,  a concerted effort to make this change would disfigure the front page for weeks. The alternative would be to do it in one go which would be massively disruptive.

2) **A lack of clarity**. Often askers want to know about things that happened in the films *and* the books. It's not often that clear what their original intention was, and hence tagging their questions isn't going to be as easy as you might think.

---

Yes, this is a good (or at least acceptable) idea but **we should wait until there's momentum for another "big tag event" before we actually do anything about it.**

Comment: @JasonBaker, our expert in Tolkien tags. has stated the use of the three tags [tag:fellowship-of-the-ring] [tag:the-two-towers] and [tag:return-og-the-king] as movie tags, to distinguish them for the books. The same goes for [tag:an-unexpected-party], [tag:desolation-of-smaug] and [tag:battle-of-the-five-armies]

Comment: @Edlothiad - I stand ready to do naff all about it.

Comment: All about the movie tags? Or tags in general

Comment: @Edlothiad - Both really. I persuaded myself to do something about some of the Star Trek tags last month, but mostly because it was annoying me personally.

Comment: I think a consensus needs to be made about the tolkien tags. And if this isn't the meta than I will ask another one. I'm debating an answer on this meta about said tags to get a consensus.

Comment: @Edlothiad - As far as I'm concerned, you're welcome to retag them gradually. You're also welcome to retag any new ones. I suspect that the outcome of this meta will be that you're not welcome to retag them **all in one go**.

Comment: I understand that. I want a consensus on how to use them to fix previous ones and future ones. Screw it I'm going to answer.